# isA relationship: how can we model it in protege? What is its difference with Instance?

Tags: sparql, ontology, semantic-web, protege, knowledge-graph

For modelling an isA relationship, (1) is it enough to just make sub-properties or sub-classes?
If not, what is the correct way?

(2) What is the difference of isA and Instance?
From what I understood, isA is a predicate for objects whereas Instance is for demonstrating individuals. But I am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include an example what you mean with "to just make sub-properties or sub-classes"? And what does "demonstrating individuals" mean?

Comment: For example, is "isA" relationship same as `rdfs:subClassOf` or `rdfs:subPropertyOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to make a sub-class, it’s enough to use the
`rdfs:subClassOf` property.

```
# "Y is-a X"
:Y rdfs:subClassOf :X .
```

In Protégé, this happens automatically if you use the "Add subclass" button.

(The same goes for `rdfs:subPropertyOf` and the "Add sub property" button.)

---

The term ***instance*** [refers to](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_classes) a member of a class.

If you say

```
ex:Arbo94 rdf:type :Y .
```

then `ex:Arbo94` is an instance of the class `:Y`, and given the `rdfs:subClassOf` statement from above, also an instance of the class `:X`.

It’s also an instance of [`rdfs:Resource`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_resource) ("the class of everything"), as everything in RDF is a member of this class.

Comment: All clear, thanks a lot!